# Does placement-new introduce a sequence point?

Tags: c++, exception, constructor, side-effects, sequence-points

Consider the following line of code:

```
new (p++) T();
```

If the constructor `T()` throws an exception, is `p` guaranteed to have already been incremented?

Comment: It's a nice question, but I hope that you would never actually write code like this :-)

Comment: @sel: Indeed, I replaced it with `new (p) T(); ++p;` because it is easier to understand and the differing semantics (*no* increment when exception is thrown) fit my program logic better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From 5.3.4 [expr.new] (quoting from n3242):

> *11* The new-placement syntax is used to
>   supply additional arguments to an
>   allocation function. If used, overload
>   resolution is performed on a function
>   call created by assembling an argument
>   list consisting of the amount of space
>   requested (the first argument) and the
>   expressions in the new-placement part
>   of the new-expression (the second and
>   succeeding arguments).

So in a new expression the allocation function is used from a function call (which makes sense). All allocation functions are functions, including the ones provided by the implementation, from 3.7.4.1 [basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]:

> *1* An allocation function shall be a class member function or a global function; [...]

So by the time an exception is thrown from the constructor, the allocation has taken place and the associated function call expression has been fully evaluated.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is guaranteed to be incremented.

The operators are just syntactic sugar for function/method calls.
I don't believe new has any special meaning above operator so it should be the same.

Thus all parameter are fully evaluated (with sequence point) before the function `new` is called.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the standard answers this question directly/explicitly. Implicitly, however, the answer is yes.

In particular, the placement syntax for new is simply a way of specifying extra parameters that will be passed to a function. Like any other function call, there is a sequence point between evaluating all the parameters to the function (in unspecified order), and executing any code in the function. I believe that should mean your `p++` will be evaluated and all side effects applied before anything else happens.

Answer (score 0):

Placement new is just a regular function, named `operator new(size_t, void*)`. It simply returns its second argument.

Comment: You are confusing placement-new with `operator new`.

Comment: Don't think so. Well, to be precize, placement-new is a syntax of calling overloaded forms of operator-new, but normal oeople just call these forms placement-new too.

Comment: Placement new and operator new are orthogonal concepts. Very orthogonal concepts. If you use placement new there is **no** call to operator new.

Answer (score -1):

The increment operator does the following:

1. stores the old value in a internal copy
2. increments by one
3. returns the old value
4. deletes the copy of the old value

So, `p` is guaranteed to be incremented.

Comment: Don't be so sure. For example, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482035/difference-in-output-of-i-i-c-and-i-i-c

Comment: The increment is not guaranteed to be visible until the next sequence point, and that is what my question is about.

Comment: Ok @FredOverflow, missed the topic in the answer, sry
@Fred Larson, your are right, i should tell: This is only the standard definition. If a compiler does it not this way, thats something else.